# How do I multiply non-numeric values in one column by numbers in a corresponding column to compile a list?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Form that asks people to enter their name and select a number between `1` and `10`. That form populates responses in a sheet like so:

```
Name1                    3
Name2                    5
Name3                    7
Name4                    1
ETC.
```

I need to compile a list of these names that includes the name repeated as many times as the number they choose. Like so:

```
Name1
Name1
Name1
Name2
Name2
Name2
Name2
Name2
ETC.
```

Is this possible?

Some of my lists get pretty long and putting them into a list manually is time consuming and easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming names in col A and numbers in B, an alternative would be to use this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(Join(char(9), rept(A2:A&char(9), B2:B)), char(9))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that should help.

---

**EDIT:**
A few changes to give control over columns.

This version specifies column B (names) and column D (numbers)

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu( 'Multiply Names' )
    .addItem( 'Multiply names', 'multiplyNames' )
    .addToUi();

} // onOpen 


function multiplyNames() {

  // get values from this sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var names = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();
  var numbers = sheet.getRange('D:D').getValues();

  // create new sheet
  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet();

  // put names on new sheet
  var totalNames = 0;

  for ( var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++ ) {
    if ( !isNaN( numbers[i][0] ) ) {

      for ( var j=0; j<numbers[i][0]; j++ ) {
        newSheet
          .getRange( totalNames + 1, 1 )
          .setValue( names[i][0] );

        totalNames++;
      }

    }
  }

}
```

[Example Spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JznXVetSy-ZE__9_R9Dp45jmPkmpPA3EbtkiBdMcWxo/edit?usp=sharing)

You can change the columns by changing the B's and D's on these lines:

```
var names = sheet.getRange('B:B').getValues();
var numbers = sheet.getRange('D:D').getValues();
```

---

To add the script to your spreadsheet:

1. click the 'Tools' menu, and select 'Script Editor...'
2. Erase everything and paste this script in
3. Save the script
4. Reload your spreadsheet

There will be a new menu item called "Multiply Names".  Use it on the sheet populated by the form.  It will create a new sheet with the names multiplied.

---

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: If they are in different columns? Names are in Column B and the numbers are in Column D.

Answer (score 0):

First, create two comma delimited lists (each in a single cell). One for the names and one for the occurances of the names. The LEFT 
and -2 removes the last ", " from the list.

=arrayformula(left(concatenate(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&", "),len(concatenate(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&", "))-2))

=arrayformula(left(concatenate(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")&", "),len(concatenate(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")&", "))-2))

Then add the below formula where you want your final list to begin. D2 references the list of comma separated names
from the first formula above. D3 references the occurance list from the second formula above. SPLIT creates arrays
and REPT repeats the created string.

=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(D2,",")&",",split(D3,",")))), ","))

Comment: Thank you all! I will try them all and see which is easiest for me. Really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

for each row, create a delimited list:

=split(rept(A1&";",B1),";")

=split(rept(A2&";",B2),";")

then in a separate column you want to transpose that array so that it lists them in a column:

=transpose(split(join(";",C1:C2),";"))